# Программа для сравнения ячеек в word

Tags: javascript, java, python

Суть программы: Есть 2 столбца в ворде. В одной ячейке установлено условие, например, ">20". В другой ячейке- значение, которое либо соответствует, либо нет заданным условиям. Условия самые разные: не более, не менее, более стольких но менее стольких и т.д. Количество ячеек может от 100 до нескольких тысяч, в ручную проверять устаешь, да и не всегда углядишь. Собственно говоря в какую сторону копать, с помощью чего можно сделать и можно ли вообще?

Comment: Используйте Excel и его функции

Comment: Попробуйте пересохранить документ в другом формате, например в `HTML` (`Word` сам может это сделать), и распарсить какой-либо библиотекой Вашего любимого ЯП.

Comment: в питоне есть модуль [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), с его помощью можно достаточно удобно работать документами ворда.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы)

Comment: если хотите подружить java с word, то вам в сторону apache poi...